# What is the meaning of {...} in php

Tags: php

new to php, came across this snippet of code and needed help to understand on how it works. is there any relation with the **splat operator** ...

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['tno']) && $_GET['tno'] !== '') 
    {
            if ((preg_match('/\d/',$_GET['tno']))) 
            {
                    echo 'Value is flag{...}';
            }
            else {
                    echo 'oops!';
            }
    }?>
```

and the HTML form has this.

```
<input type="text" id="tno" name="tno">
```

Comment: That's a simple [string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

Answer (score 1):

It is just a series of characters in a string literal. They have no special syntax meaning there.

Comment: Thanks @quentin,but what is the significance of using {...} rather than direct string.it just prints 'Value is flag{...}'

Comment: @oneinbillion — There is no significance. It **does** just print `{...}`.

Comment: @oneinbillion It's a single-quoted string. It prints the exact text you type inside, that's the whole point.